# Console logging does not appear when creating object instance

Tags: javascript

Code snippet 1:

```
<script>
function Person(lastName, firstName){ 
  this.lastName = lastName; 
  this.firstName = firstName; 
}
var DnnyGdmn = new Person("Goodman","Danny"); 
var DvdFlngn = new Person("Flanagan","David"); 
function Book(title, pages, price){ 
  this.title = title; 
  this.pages = pages; 
  this.price = price; 
  this.authors = new Array(arguments.length-3);
  console.log(arguments);
  for(i = 0; i < arguments.length - 3; i++){ 
    this.authors[i] = arguments[i + 3]; 
  } 
}
var JavaNut = new Book("Java Foundation Classes in a Nutshell", 731, 29.95, DvdFlngn); 
var JSTDR = new Book("Javascript: The Definitive Guide (3rd  Edition)", 776, 39.95, DvdFlngn); 
</script>
```

In Firefox firebug->console->all, I see:

```
["Java Foundation Classes in a Nutshell", 731, 29.95, Person { lastName="Flanagan", firstName="David"}]
["Javascript: The Definitive Guide (3rd Edition)", 776, 39.95, Person { lastName="Flanagan", firstName="David"}]
```

Code snippet 2:

```
<script>
function Person(lastName, firstName){ 
  this.lastName = lastName; 
  this.firstName = firstName; 
}
var DnnyGdmn = new Person("Goodman","Danny"); 
var DvdFlngn = new Person("Flanagan","David"); 
</script>
```

In Firefox firebug->console->all, it does not show anything.

Question:

Both code snippets do the same thing, creating an instance of a certain object, but why does 1 write something to console, while code 2 does not?

Comment: Where do you use `console.log` in your second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `codes 1`, you have this:

```
console.log(arguments);
```

This can be found here:

```
  ...
  this.pages = pages;
  this.price = price;

  this.authors = new Array(arguments.length-3); console.log(arguments);

  for(i=0;i<arguments.length-3;i++){
    this.authors[i] = arguments[i+3];
  }
  ...
```

This code writes the arguments value to the `console`. Since the code is not present in the `codes 2`, it doesn't output anything in the console.